# Search for a Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, selection-tools

I have a material that belongs to some objects, but I can't find those objects. **Is there a way to search for objects that have been assigned a certain material?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. What you can do is use the *Search engine* tool in the *Outliner*. Since various aspects of each object's *Object Data* (including materials) are listed in the *Outliner*, the *Search engine* tool will turn them up as results. Note that you may have to <kbd>[image: MW] MW</kbd> scroll to bring the search bar into view.

[image]